# Configure multiple login sessions using google oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, odoo, google-authentication

I am using Google OAuth for Google signin with Odoo.

Everything works fine and I can sign in using google with no problem. However, *I cannot open multiple sessions using my same google credentials*.

**For example, if I open two sessions, one in chrome and another in    firefox, then the older session gets logged out.**

I don't understand what's the problem because no matter how many sessions I start **if I log in using my username and password separately**, without using google OAuth, **none of the sessions get logged out** - works fine.

I was wondering it has got something to do with the code, so I did a lot of tweaks but nothing works. I saw that at one point it cannot get the session information of older sessions. However my question is not about the code.

My question is, **is there any configuration** or setting to be set in **google OAuth or Odoo 8 which lets users have multiple sessions at the same time** or is there any setting while using google OAuth with Odoo that I need to know for this?

Any idea would be really helpful as I've been struggling for days with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have build a module for Odoo V9. Without this module, Odoo save only one token. But when you use odoo in multi computer, you use one token for each computer.

By default odoo don't support multi token. You need to modify the code of module auth_oauth.

With this module it save all token, like that you can have multi connection.

You can donwload and instal this module : https://github.com/IguanaYachts/auth_oauth_multi_token.git

```
class ResUsers(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.users'

oauth_access_token_ids = fields.One2many('auth.oauth.multi.token', 'user_id', 'Tokens', copy=False)
oauth_access_max_token = fields.Integer('Number of simultaneous connections', default=5, required=True)

@api.model
def _auth_oauth_signin(self, provider, validation, params):
    res = super(ResUsers, self)._auth_oauth_signin(provider, validation, params)

    oauth_uid = validation['user_id']
    user_ids = self.search([('oauth_uid', '=', oauth_uid), ('oauth_provider_id', '=', provider)]).ids
    if not user_ids:
        raise openerp.exceptions.AccessDenied()
    assert len(user_ids) == 1

    self.oauth_access_token_ids.create({'user_id': user_ids[0],
                                        'oauth_access_token': params['access_token'],
                                        'active_token': True,
                                        })
    return res

@api.multi
def clear_token(self):
    for users in self:
        for token in users.oauth_access_token_ids:
            token.write({
                'oauth_access_token': "****************************",
                'active_token': False})

@api.model
def check_credentials(self, password):
    try:
        return super(ResUsers, self).check_credentials(password)
    except openerp.exceptions.AccessDenied:
        res = self.env['auth.oauth.multi.token'].sudo().search([
            ('user_id', '=', self.env.uid),
            ('oauth_access_token', '=', password),
            ('active_token', '=', True),
        ])
        if not res:
            raise
```

Answer (score -1):

If you follow the steps above you will be able to successfully configure Google Apps (Gmail) with OpenERP via the OAuth module. The only thing i was missing is an extra step I found in a youtube video; you have to:

- Go to Settings - Users
- To the users you want to give OAuth access, send them a password reset by using the "Send reset password instructions by email" option.
- Ask your users (or yourself) to use the link they receive in their email, but, when they open it, they will only see the log in screen with the "Log in with Google" option. (no typical change password option available)
- Use the proper Google account and voila! - Now it connects smoothly.

> - The Youtube video that show how to log in with Google in OpenERP: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-iwzxEeJmc

and if configuration of Oauth2 and odoo see this link for more detail

> https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/setting-up-google-apps-authentication-for-odoo/

Comment: Like I said, everything is working fine. I had already done the extra step long ago. But that's not the problem. The problem is that it can't retain older sessions. Only the most recent session is retained and all older ones are logged out.